# Creating a new column in Pandas that is True if there is data in another two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

In my pandas dataset, there are two columns (i.e. A and B) from which I wish to create a third column (C) that is "True" if either A or B is filled.

I have trialed the following code. However, after running this code, all the values in column C are "No" (indicating all cells in columns A and B are empty, however this is not the case).

```
df['C'] = C
C = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df['a'].isnull() is False:
        c.append("Yes")
    elif df['b'].isnull() is False:
        c.append("Yes")
    else:
        c.append("No")
```

I'm new to Python (and StackOverflow, too), so if anyone has any suggestions they will be most appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you calling your dataframe `pd` when `pd` is the universally-accepted alias for the pandas module itself?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: Read the Pandas docs. Read the Pandas docs. Read the Pandas docs. Read the Pandas docs.

Comment: Also, why do you want to use the strings `'Yes'` and `'No'`, when boolean values are a thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `np.where` for the following conditions:

```
df['c'] = np.where((df['a'].isnull()) & (df['b'].isnull()),"No","Yes")
```

Of course you would need to `import numpy as np`

Comment: Gracias, Ansev!

Comment: True, the original one was correct. If any of them is not null, then Yes, otherwise No

Comment: You can also access numpy from within pandas via `pd.np` assuming pandas is imported as pd

Comment: is it new in Pandas 1.0.0 @Emil Mirzayev?

Comment: No, I have been using it for a long time now. Not sure from which version they have it, but they have had it for long time

Comment: Why are you using the strings `'Yes'` and `'No'`, when boolean values are a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to check when `a` or `b` notnull,  then we can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the boolean series created with `Yes` or `No`:

```
df['c'] = df[['a','b']].notnull().any(axis = 1).map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})

#alternative
#df['c'] = df[['a','b']].notnull().any(axis = 1).replace({True:'Yes',False:'No'})

#logic inverse
#df['c'] = df[['a','b']].notnull().any(axis = 1).map({True:'No',False:'Yes'})
```

or

```
import numpy as np
df['c'] = np.where(df[['a','b']].notnull().any(axis = 1),'Yes','No')
#df['c'] = pd.np.where(df[['a','b']].notnull().any(axis = 1),'Yes','No')
#logic inverse
#df['c'] = np.where(df[['a','b']].notnull().any(axis = 1),'No','Yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
#df is the dataframe you are working with

# using dataframe indexing
df['c'] = (df['a'].isnull() & df['b'].isnull())

# using apply
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: False if pd.isna(df['a']) and  pd.isna(df['b']) else True ,axis=1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):
     if x[0].isna():
          return "Yes"
     elif x[1].isna():
          return "Yes"
     return "No"
```

then try :

```
df['C'] = df[['A','B']].apply(f,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if(pd.isnull(row['a'])) and (pd.isnull(row['b'])):
        C.append("No")
    else:
        C.append("Yes")

df.insert(2, "C", C)
```